# detectar click fuera de fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

tengo un fragment que necesito que se cierre al clickear fuera de el, este es el codigo que tengo:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
        Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentoLeyes);
        if (currentFragment!=null) {
            currentFragment.getView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);
            if (currentFragment instanceof VideoFragment) {
                if (!dialogBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

el problema que tiene el codigo, es que cuando doy click dentro del fragment, lo cierra y solo necesito que se cierre cuando el click o tap es fuera de este

Comment: Hola zhet de donde obtuviste este código? Donde mandas llamar este método?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor en este caso es sobrescribir el método `onTouchEvent()`, al tocar el `Fragment` detecta las coordenadas mediante un `Rect`:

```
          Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            currentFragment.getView().getHitRect(r);
            boolean  intersects = r.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
```

y esto determinará si estas tocando fuera del `Fragment` para proceder a eliminarlo.

Este sería un ejemplo:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            currentFragment.getView().getHitRect(r);
            boolean  intersects = r.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

        if (!intersects) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pressing INSIDE the Fragment.\nRemoving Fragment!!!");
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.remove(currentFragment).commit();

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent (event);
}
```